# My js script is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I want to have a result based on grading set by my script. But it's not giving me the result as expected. It's not doing anything in fact.

Below is the code:

```js
<script>
function rateMe()
{
var a = "";
var x = document.getElementById("id1").value;

if (x < 10) {a = "Bad";}
if (x < 50) {a = "Average";}
if (x < 75) {a = "Good";}
if (x < 100) {a = "Best";}

var y = document.getElementById("id2") + a;
}
y;
</script>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. You can’t use `y` outside of your function like that.

Comment: The variable "y" is scoped only to the function. So outside of it, it is undefined. Either declare "y" outside of the function and then query the value (after running the function) or look into the keyword "return" abd how it may help you.

Comment: Actually there's a ton going wonky here. The value returned from the DOM I'd always a string. So you should convert it to a number. Your "var y = " line is retrieving a vlaue not setting one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you figure it out?

Just a few comments about your approach.

- The variable `y` does not exist outside the function block! So, maybe you want to return this value as an output or can also declare it outside.
- You can use

`if (x<10) {
 } else if (x<50) {
 } else if (x<100) {
 }`

instead of the current solution to avoid checking for every condition, if you want to have just one hit.

In your case, if x = 1, x < 100 and you will get "Best" as result.

```js
var x = 5;

if (x < 10) {a = "Bad";}
else if (x < 50) {a = "Average";}
else if (x < 75) {a = "Good";}
else if (x < 100) {a = "Best";}

console.log(a);
```

By the way, you can use `console.log(y)` to check if everything is ok!

Hope it help!

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!!. The only problem with my script was the absence of "else if". Therefore, the script only returned the answer "Best" as every value was less than 100. It returned the value from the last available condition.